# end of month data with inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join

I am trying got get last day of month price based on daily data. ISIN is in the mapping table and date etc is the content table. How should I construct the query so it works?

```
select b.isin, last_Day(a.date) End_date, a.PRICE 
from MAPPING b,
     CONTENT a  
where b.ISIN in ('xxx')
  and a.date >= '31Jul2010' AND a.date <= '31Aug2010'
  and a.instid = b.instid
```

I should get 1 result, not the daily results but with the last day of the particular month

```
b.isin  last_day    a.price
xxx 31/08/2010      p1
xxx 31/08/2010      p2
xxx 31/08/2010      p3
xxx 31/08/2010      p4
xxx 31/08/2010      p5
xxx 31/08/2010      p6
xxx 31/08/2010      p7
xxx 31/08/2010      p8
xxx 31/08/2010      p9
xxx 31/08/2010      p10
xxx 31/08/2010      p11
xxx 31/08/2010      p12
xxx 31/08/2010      p13
xxx 31/08/2010      p14
xxx 31/08/2010      p15
xxx 31/08/2010      p16
xxx 31/08/2010      p17
xxx 31/08/2010      p18
xxx 31/08/2010      p19
xxx 31/08/2010      p20
xxx 31/08/2010      p21
xxx 31/08/2010      p22
```

I kept the isin and price hidden on purpose(these are not the actual results).
But the logic is the same. Should be xxx 31/08.2010 a.price and like this for every month in a range of choice.

Comment: Tip of today: switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: You haven't shown the original data that produces that output; is there one row per date? Is there always (exactly) one row for the last day of every month?

Comment: Yes, exactly one row per date. Price is always different, ISIN is always the same. As in the database prices are daily, I would like to obtain for a particular time frame (eg 3 yrs) monthly data. Thanks for the input, I will try your solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the last day of each month, and the price on the last day you have data for (which may not be the last day of the month, if you have gaps in your data):

```
-- CTEs to generate fake data
with content (instid, a_date, price) as (
  select 42, date '2010-08-09' + level, 'p'||level
  from dual connect by level <= 22
),
mapping (instid, isin) as (
  select 42, 'xxx' from dual
)
select b.isin,
  last_day(a.a_date) as last_day,
  max(a.price) keep (dense_rank last order by a.a_date) as price
from mapping b
join content a
on a.instid = b.instid
where b.isin in ('xxx')
and a.a_date >= date '2010-07-31' AND a.a_date <= date '2010-08-31'
group by b.isin, last_day(a.a_date);

ISI LAST_DAY   PRICE                                   
--- ---------- -----------------------------------------
xxx 2010-08-31 p22
```

With data for July and August generated in a similar way, you get:

```
ISI LAST_DAY   PRICE                                   
--- ---------- -----------------------------------------
xxx 2010-07-31 p22                                      
xxx 2010-08-31 p52
```

This uses the [`keep dense_rank`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm#SQLRF00641) analytic method to find the latest price within the group.